# video.js and fancybox - video plays automatically on fancybox open

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, fancybox, video.js

I am using [fancy box](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox) to open an html snippet that includes a [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/) player.

My problem is the player autoplays when it is opened in a lightbox, something about the initialization of the lightbox is triggering the video to play. I don't want the video to autoplay, I want the lightbox to open and it show the video normally, with the play button over the poster image chosen. The video loads normally and doesn't autoplay when the same code is used outside of the lightbox.

I am developing using jekyll and in chrome.

Here is my html snippet that is opened in a lightbox:

```
<div style="display: none" class="video-lightbox" id="acwedding">
  <div class="lb-vid-content">
    <div class="lb-vid">
      <video
        class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered vjs-16-9"
        controls
        preload="auto"
        poster="posters/acwedding.jpg"
        data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/248666889.hd.mp4?s=efe468ee4ee8ae545fa9cf0a8a985788bb4409d9&profile_id=175" type="video/mp4"></source>
        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
          <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
        </p>
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="lb-vid-desc">
      <h2 class="lb-vid-title">Chris and Allison's Wedding Video</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not too experienced with javaScript but I suspect I can do something to delay initialization of the video.js player until the lightbox is opened. But I'm not sure how to do that nor if it is even the right thing to do. I appreciate any help!

Comment: try autoplay = 0

Comment: that in fact causes the video to play before the lightbox is even opened. video.js by default doesn't autoplay and any mention of autoplay in the video tag is actually telling it to autoplay regardless of whether it is false or 0 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is a play() trigger in fancybox that is causing the video.js player to play.  I simply deleted this trigger from the fancybox code and so far so good! Probably not an ideal solution as its a little quick and dirty but so far for my purposes it's doing the job.

If you are experiencing the same issue and like to use my fix, search the fancybox js file for '.trigger("play")' and delete it. I'll update if any issues arise from this fix.

Comment: Why would you not want to play it when lightbox starts?

Comment: I'd like to be able to have multiple videos in one lightbox potentially. I also would like to give the user the option to watch the video or not after opening the lightbox.  Also for slower connections instead of preloading behind the poster, it sits there with a loading graphic that covers the poster image if it plays immediately.

Comment: But what if user does not want to make that one extra click to view video? I did not understand the preloading part - lightbox script is not preloading the video; there is no any difference or gain if user has slower connection.

Comment: Video.js allows you to preload the video behind a chosen image. If the video plays immediately, no chance for it to preload, and no chance for the image to be seen cleanly as a loading animation appears over it.  The lightbox will contain a description of the video as well and I'd like the user to read the description before watching the video in most cases so autoplay is not ideal. Also as I said, having more than one video creates a problem and multiple videos start playing at once.

Comment: You say that "Video.js allows you to preload the video behind a chosen image", but you also said that you care about user having slow internet connection. Sounds like a contradiction to me, especially if you have multiple videos. Also, the lightbox is not starting multiple videos at once, quite the opposite - it starts the current one and stops if user closes or changes next/prev.

Comment: Also, why do you assume that user is not able to read the description while video is playing? All these assumptions does not sound reasonable.

Comment: Why are you arguing with me about my own chosen design? You haven't a clue about the nature of my site nor its content. I would like the user to read a description before watching the video. This is impossible if the video starts playing immediately. Preloading allows the video to load before play is pressed so that when it is pressed it can play immediately and there is no loading graphic. I find this to be ideal. If there are multiple videos in one lightbox, does it not start playing all videos in the lightbox at the same time? If it doesn't I'd still like the user to pick which one to watch

Comment: Just think about the user experience - 1) user has to click to start lightbox to read the description ; 2) user has to click twice to start video. Very annoying. Maybe it suits you, so, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following option to your fancybox :

```
video: { autoStart: false }
```